# Why is this Python code not replacing 'x' with 'z'?

Tags: python

```
 with open('text-a1.txt') as f:
    c = f.read()

c.replace('x', 'z')
print(c)
```

Why is this code not replacing all 'x's in the file 'text-a1.txt' to 'z's?

Comment: Change `c.replace('x', 'z')` to `c = c.replace('x', 'z')`, more details the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the string after replacement as below. It is not an inplace operation. Read more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp). -

```
c = 'abcdxyz'

c = c.replace('x', 'z') #<----
print(c)
```

```
abcdzyz #<- notice the x changed to z as expected
```

---

In short, change `c.replace('x', 'z')` to `c = c.replace('x', 'z')`

Answer (score 1):

`.replace` is not "in place" operation, it **returns** a string with replaced characters.

```
with open('text-a1.txt') as f:
    c = f.read()

c = c.replace('x', 'z') # Note the change here
print(c)
```

In general **strings in Python are immutable**. It means you will never be able to change a string, you will always create **a new one** with some modifications.

Comment: What would I have to change for it to work?

Comment: Answer provides you with the change - just assign result of .replace to a variable